# Chrome Extension trouble with getting a ContextMenu to only load for a specific page

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, contextmenu

I've started with the `contextMenu` example from Google. It creates a context menu using a background page which applies to all pages.

I'm looking for a way to create the context menu's only specifically for a page. The example page I'm trying to target is any Reddit page.

My `manifest.json`:

```
{
  "name": "Context Menus Sample",
  "description": "Shows some of the features of the Context Menus API",
  "version": "0.6",
  "permissions": ["contextMenus"],

  "manifest_version": 2,
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["http://www.reddit.com/*"],
      "js": ["sample.js"]
    }
  ]
}
```

`sample.js` is the same one [from the original `contextMenu` example project](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/examples/api/contextMenus/basic/sample.js) supplied by Google Examples. It was originally a background page script, I've moved it to a content script section so that it will only load for the specified (Reddit) URL.

Example code from sample.js:

```
var checkbox1 = chrome.contextMenus.create(
  {"title": "Checkbox1", "type": "checkbox", "onclick": checkboxOnClick}
);
```

So my confusion lies with why the contextmenu doesn't show up when you are on reddit.com. I'm under the impression that the sample.js triggers when the url matches.

Comment: Communication between extensions and their content scripts works by using message passing. You should trigger the content script injection by this way. Follow up this link: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging

Comment: @Nick SO is best kept to a Q&A format; your answer-in-a-question does not conform. You can answer your own question, even if you accept a different answer - so please edit your update out of the question itself into an answer. Thanks.

Comment: Done, sorry that does make more sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You [can't use (most) of the `chrome.*` APIs from a content script](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts). Your `sample.js` runs, but the API call fails.

Instead, you should move it back to a background script, and read the docs on [`chrome.contextMenus.create()`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contextMenus#method-create).

Specifically, you can pass the `documentUrlPatterns` parameter to limit where the context menu appears:

```
var checkbox1 = chrome.contextMenus.create({
    "title": "Checkbox1",
    "type": "checkbox",
    "onclick": checkboxOnClick,
    "documentUrlPatterns": ["*://*.reddit.com/*"]
});
```

Answer (score 1):

**Update**

I went back to the original `manifest.json` which contained only the context menu:

```
{
  "name": "Context Menus Sample",
  "description": "Shows some of the features of the Context Menus API",
  "version": "0.6",
  "permissions": ["contextMenus"],
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["sample.js"]
  },
  "manifest_version": 2
}
```

I proceeded to change the `sample.js` line that creates the first menu item (mind you this is all a learning experience):

from:

```
for (var i = 0; i < contexts.length; i++) {
  var context = contexts[i];
  var title = "Test '" + context + "' menu item";
  var id = chrome.contextMenus.create({"title": title, "contexts":[context],"onclick": genericOnClick});
  console.log("'" + context + "' item:" + id);
}
```

to this (changing only the `var id` part:

```
for (var i = 0; i < contexts.length; i++) {
  var context = contexts[i];
  var title = "Test '" + context + "' menu item";
  var id = chrome.contextMenus.create({
    "title": title,
    "contexts": [context],
    "onclick": genericOnClick,
    "documentUrlPatterns": ["*://*.reddit.com/*"]
  });
  console.log("'" + context + "' item:" + id);
}
```

**Conclusion**

The above changes now make the first menu item accessible only if you are within a reddit page. So it won't be hard from this point to figure out the rest of my extension. Thank you guys for the assistance.

My apologies to the editors for my terrible format. I was new to this site, new to extensions, and unfortunately up hours past my normal hour of sleep. I will try to not subject you to that kind of stupidity again.

Comment: We're not editors, we're just long-time users. And it's absolutely fine considering you're new. As long as you take constructive criticism - you'll be a fine member of the community.